# Resizing the address bar in Chrome to show more extensions

Tags: google-chrome

I cannot resize the address bar in Chrome to show more extensions since the recent update of Chrome

Chrome version Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Mac OSX Catalina Version 10.15.5 (19F101)

Image below shows that there is now resize toggle

[image: me]

Comment: The redesigned toolbar works differently. You need to pin the extensions explicitly inside the extension menu that appears when you click the puzzle piece icon in the toolbar.

Comment: That's great - thank you

It is REALLY irritating - as sometimes I want to copy partial contents from the address bar - is there a way to resize the address bar?

Comment: No, but you can scroll inside the address bar, it's just like any other width-constrained input box.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks, mate. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Puzzle piece next to the address bar, then you can pin extensions next to the puzzle piece and their icons will display between the puzzle piece and the address bar. Easy Peasy.